# JQuery theme builder CSS issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

For some reason the hover attribute is not working. When i put my mouse over the button, it doesn't change to the color I specified in the CSS.

Here's my relevant CSS:

```
.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default {
    border: 1px solid #dadada;
    background: #d7dfff url(images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_75_d7dfff_1x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #555555;
}

.ui-state-default a, .ui-state-default a:link, .ui-state-default a:visited {
    color: #555555;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-hover, .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-focus {
    border: 1px solid #dadada;
    background: #b3c2ff url(images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_75_b3c2ff_1x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #212121;
}

.ui-state-hover a, .ui-state-hover a:hover {
    color: #212121;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Here's the relevant HTML:

```
<button class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-state-hover" type="submit" id="barlogin"><p>Login</p></button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jquery-ui requires that you initialize the buttons using the following in your document ready/onload function:

```
$("button").button();
```

This will automatically add the $.hover() functionality with the correct removal/addition of the respective css classes.

You can read more at the [documentation page](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Button) - the more useful stuff is towards the bottom.

Also, in your css you posted, the `:hover` with the `color:` is only applied to anchor tags - not buttons.

Quick intro for jquery-ui buttons:
Script:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/jquery-ui-1.8.5.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('button').button();
   });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div>Click here to submit: <button type="submit">Submit</button></div>
```

What CSS classes jquery will add automatically for you:

```
<button class="ui-button ui-button-text-only ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
   <span class="ui-button-text">Button Label</span>
</button>
```

Note that the ui-state can also be `ui-state-hover`, `ui-state-active` or `ui-state-disabled`.

It also adds handlers for the hover, exit hover, disabled, events in javascript and switches classes in/out as needed.